# LibGDX dynamically build (fast) Model

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I am creating a voxel-like game where the voxels are smaller than your average minecraft clone. These voxels do not have an ID to determine the type of block, but a colour.

My scenery objects, which consist of tiny voxels, are constructed from binary data which holds per-voxel  colour integers. These then build a small model from the voxels.

The problem with this is that it does not accept my tiny meshes with their colours, but demands that I supply a Material which overwrites all the other colours. I have also tried another alternative which made a lot of tiny models but that was simply too slow.

What I currently have, which renders the scene white:

```
private void buildFromColours(int[][][] colours) {
    MeshBuilder mb = new MeshBuilder();
    ModelBuilder mm = new ModelBuilder();
    mm.begin();

    List<Mesh> meshes = new LinkedList<Mesh>();
    for (int x = 0; x < colours.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < colours[x].length; y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < colours[x][y].length; z++) {
                int col = colours[x][y][z];

                if ((col & 0xFF) == 0) {
                    continue;
                }


                mb.begin(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
                mb.setColor(new Color(col));
                mb.box(x, y, z, 1, 1, 1);
                Mesh m = mb.end();
                meshes.add(m);
            }
        }
    }

    Mesh finalMesh = Mesh.create(true, meshes.toArray(new Mesh[0]));
    mm.part("box", finalMesh, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material()); /* I have to specify a material :( */
    model = new ModelInstance(mm.end());
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go now. I must be able to specify an Environment when rendering so rendering a group of meshes with a shader will not work.

Comment: I can assure you that material doesn't overwrite vertex colors (they are two very different things). You simply never specified that you want to use vertex color, causing them not to be included. Consider adding `VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked`. Btw, consider reading https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBuilder%2C-MeshBuilder-and-MeshPartBuilder

Comment: @Xoppa Thank you for mentioning that! I'll have a look immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can assure you that material doesn't overwrite vertex colors (they are two very different things). You simply never specified that you want to use vertex color, causing them not to be included. Consider adding `VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked`.

Btw, you might want to reconsider your approach (voxels require special attention, MeshBuilder doesn't really fit for that). If you still do want to use ModelBuilder/MeshBuilder (you only need one of them, not both), then consider reading https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBuilder%2C-MeshBuilder-and-MeshPartBuilder

Comment: What would be a good alternative when using voxels? I understand that I need to do face culling but would you please mention the special attention I'm forgetting about? :)

Comment: There's currently no voxel engine included with libgdx. There is however a test included (https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/voxel) and there are a few tutorials about it, e.g. http://blogg.rhapsody.st/voxel-engine-and-libgdx/